# Can I exchange the derivative and integral if differetiation is w.r.t. boundary variable?

Tags: real-analysis, integration, derivatives, definite-integrals

Does
$$
\frac{d\int_{-\infty}^a a f(x) \; dx}{da} = \int_{-\infty}^a f(x) \;dx
$$
hold in general? Can you give a formal proof?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

No, you cannot. Notice that you can rewrite the expression as

$$\frac{d}{da} \left(a \int_{-\infty}^a f\right) = a f(a) + \int_{-\infty}^a f.$$

Comment: Can you explain to me why $\frac{d}{da} \left[ \int_{-\infty}^{a} -(x-a)f(x) \; dx + \int_{a}^{\infty} (x-a)f(x) \; dx \right] = \int_{-\infty}^{a} f(x) \; dx - \int_{a}^{\infty} f(x) \; dx $. I am stuck. $f(x)$ is a pdf.